# Failed to create consumer: No provider for SASL mechanism GSSAPI:Current build options: PLAIN SASL_SCRAM OAUTHBEARER

Tags: go, ssl, apache-kafka, gssapi

I m trying to create a consumer but getting error "Failed to create consumer: No provider for SASL mechanism GSSAPI: recompile librdkafka with libsasl2 or openssl support. Current build options: PLAIN SASL_SCRAM OAUTHBEARER". where, in consumer, having this config

```
 config := &kafka.ConfigMap{
                "metadata.broker.list":            cfg.BrokerHostEndpoint,
                "security.protocol":               "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
                "sasl.kerberos.service.name": "kafka",
                "group.id":                        cfg.ConsumeTopic,
                "auto.offset.reset":               "earliest",
                "go.application.rebalance.enable": true,
                "go.events.channel.enable":        true,
        }
```

Comment: Try sarama instead, otherwise, as it says `recompile librdkafka with libsasl2 or openssl support`

Comment: what if, if I compile librdkafka with libsasl2? what libsasl2 is doing actually..

Comment: It is a C library that allows the use of the SASL protocol. `confluent_go_kafka` calls out to C functions using `librdkafka`. Sarama, on the other hand, does not.